# Segmentation error due to the use of a char **

Tags: c, struct, malloc, glibc

I have to program a function that browses a map that I have previously stored in a `char **`.  At each `char` I have to check if the 8 characters that surround it and check if on these 9 there are at least 2 that correspond to `'#'`, so I created a `struct *matrix` that is supposed to check this.

I am only allowed to use the following functions/system calls: `malloc, free, exit, (f)open, (f)close, (f)read, (f)write, getline, ioctl, usleep, sigaction, signal, stat, lstat, fstat`

The problem is that despite the fact that I check if the array exists, the program returns a segmentation fault.

Here are the 2 functions that concern the matrix structure:

```c
matrix_t *create_matrix(char **map, size_t y, size_t x)
{
    matrix_t *out = malloc(sizeof(matrix_t));
    if (!out) {
        my_perr("[ERROR] Memory's allocation failure\n");
    }
    out->nbr = 0;
    set_mat_nbr(out, map, y - 1, x);
    set_mat_nbr(out, map, y, x);
    set_mat_nbr(out, map, y + 1, x);
    return out;
}
```

```c
void set_mat_nbr(matrix_t *matrix, char **map, long y, long x)
{
    if (y != 0 && map[y] != NULL && x != 0 && map[y][x - 1] == '#') {
        matrix->nbr++;
    }
    if (y != 0 && map[y] != NULL && map[y][x] == '#') {
        matrix->nbr++;
    }
    if (y != 0 && map[y] != NULL && map[y][x + 1] == '#') {
        matrix->nbr++;
    }
}
```

And here is the calling function (This one is not finished yet and only checks the top border for the moment) :

```c
void check_border(char **map)
{
    size_t y = 0, x = 0;
    matrix_t *matrix = NULL;
    while (map[0][x] != '\0') {
        matrix = create_matrix(map, 0, x);
        if (matrix->nbr < 2) {
            my_perr("[ERROR] Corrupted border\n");
        }
        free(matrix);
        x++;
    }
}
```

According to valgrind, the segfault is triggered on the 3 if() of set_mat_nbr().
Do you know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: In the `set_mat_nbr` function you never make sure that ``map` itself is not null. And you use `x - 1` without checking if `x` is larger than zero. And you use `x + 1`without checking that `x` is less than the size minus one. And the `y != 0` check doesn't check the bounds of `y`, so `y` could be out of bounds. How do you call `check_border`? What is `map` originally? How do you create it? How do you initialize it? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Also, if you have used a debugger to catch the crash, exactly *which* of the shown lines does it happen on? What are the values of `y`, `x` and `map[y]`?

Comment: The first (only!) call to `create_matrix()` passes `0` for the value of `y`... That function then makes 3 calls to `set_mat_nbr()`, the first one passing `0 - 1` as the value of `y'`... Unfortunately, the simple minded `set_mat_nbr()` attempts to use `-1` as an index value to `map[]`... Valgrind will object, with good reason. ... Oh, well... That's "Life", sometimes...

Comment: Ok here are the important functions of my code: https://godbolt.org/z/YK3PvEv89
And here is the valgrind dump:  https://pastebin.com/Jv4c1ZxF
I'd also replaced size_t from set_mat_nbr() by long (not unsigned).

Comment: Because you use `size_t` as the coordinate types for `x` and `y` (which is good), it will lead `y - 1` to become a *very* large value if `y` is zero Which it always is with the code you show. Same with `x - 1`, if `x == 0` (which it will be) then that will also result in a very large value that is *far* out of bounds. You need to do the `y` bounds checking in `create_matrix`. And do `x` bounds checking in `set_mat_nbr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all, I have corrected the problem and everything works now. Here is the new code:

```
void set_mat_nbr(matrix_t *matrix, char **map, size_t y, size_t x)
{
    if (x == 0) {
        (map[y][x] == '#') ? matrix->nbr++ : 0;
        (map[y][x + 1] == '#') ? matrix->nbr++ : 0;
    } else if (map[y][x] == '\0') {
        (map[y][x - 1] == '#') ? matrix->nbr++ : 0;
        (map[y][x] == '#') ? matrix->nbr++ : 0;
    } else {
        (map[y][x - 1] == '#') ? matrix->nbr++ : 0;
        (map[y][x] == '#') ? matrix->nbr++ : 0;
        (map[y][x + 1] == '#') ? matrix->nbr++ : 0;
    }
}
```

And :

```
matrix_t *create_matrix(char **map, size_t y, size_t x)
{
    matrix_t *out = malloc(sizeof(matrix_t));
    if (!out)
        my_perr("[ERROR] Memory's allocation failure\n");
    out->nbr = 0;
    if (y == 0) {
        if (!map[y + 1]) {
            set_mat_nbr(out, map, y, x);
        } else {
            set_mat_nbr(out, map, y, x);
            set_mat_nbr(out, map, y + 1, x);
        }
    } else if (!map[y + 1]) {
        set_mat_nbr(out, map, y, x);
        set_mat_nbr(out, map, y - 1, x);
    } else {
        set_mat_nbr(out, map, y - 1, x);
        set_mat_nbr(out, map, y, x);
        set_mat_nbr(out, map, y + 1, x);
    }
    return out;
}
```